# Securing PubSub push endpoints in node app engine?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm using pubsub to push messages into an App Engine app written in node on the flexible environment. Is there a way I can limit my endpoints to only traffic from pubsub?

In the standard environment, App Engine has handlers that can define admin only requests and secure endpoints. However, this functionality is not available in the flexible environment. Is it possible to set up Firewall rules for only Google requests (Firewall appears to be application wide, not endpoint?), is there a standard method to secure endpoints or do I need to custom roll a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out Google has posted a solution to this [in the docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/writing-and-responding-to-pub-sub-messages).

The solution is:

Create a token in your app.yaml environment:

```
env_variables:
 PUBSUB_TOPIC: <your-topic-name>
 # This token is used to verify that requests originate from your
 # application. It can be any sufficiently random string.
 PUBSUB_VERIFICATION_TOKEN: <your-verification-token>
```

Send the token with your message:

```
 https://YOUR_APP_ID.appspot.com/pubsub/push?token=YOUR_TOKEN \
--ack-deadline 10
```

Check the token in your push handler:

```
  if (req.query.token !== PUBSUB_VERIFICATION_TOKEN) {
    res.status(400).send();
    return;
  }
```

RTFM!

Comment: While this technically works, it is quite a primitive method of implementing security...Is there a better way?

Comment: Yep - there is something better now. My answer shows how. The google docs were a bit hard to navigate and confusing.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, using a hardcoded verification token is not a recommended secure approach.

The docs are not exactly clear for App Engine and I raised [an issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/issues/2794) to see if they can improve.

1. [Enable Authentication](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push#properties_of_a_push_subscription) in your subscription and assign a service account
2. In your endpoint you will need to read the bearer token from the `Authorization` header and use the `OAuth2Client` from `google-auth-library` to parse and validate it
3. Assert the claims from the parsed token

The GCP docs page does not show this example, although their [samples repo](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/blob/b0257afe31f3a41f54ab4342a71ed579e4d9d135/appengine/pubsub/app.js#L93) shows it, albeit with some confusing code.

If you are using `express` then steps 2,3 are suited to middleware and we have written a simple small library with the appropriate middleware for you to use. See [gae-js-google-auth](https://github.com/mondo-mob/gae-js/tree/main/packages/gae-js-google-auth) and the example below for validating the email matches your desired service account email (as well as the internal assertions that the lib does).

```js
// Apply middleware however you normally would
app.use("/pubsub", requiresGoogleJwt({
   email: "your-service-account@your-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}));

// Now any matching routes will be protected
app.post("/pubsub/start-job", (req, res) => res.send("OK"));
app.post("/pubsub/poll-status", (req, res) => res.send("OK"));
```