# How to Secure App Engine Pub/Sub Push Endpoint Triggered by GCS?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm trying to find a way to secure my google cloud app engine standard environment endpoint subscribed to a push pub/sub topic triggered by the creation of a file on google cloud storage.

Since it's only possible to set IP address to the firewall rules of app engine and pub/sub doesn't have a predefined set of IP address it's not possible to use this feature. It's also not possible to use a custom header on pub/sub call and check its validity on the app engine since I have no control over the pub/sub request.

Any suggestion on how to secure the app engine endpoint?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloud Pub/Sub push does **not** play well with **IP based firewall rules**. Making your push notification **security based on IP addresses is not the most efficient way**.

> **OAuth and Service Accounts** can useful to **authenticate access** to Google products, such as [Cloud Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/authentication#supported-authentication-methods). This will **prevent outsiders from accessing your Pub/Sub** API for as long as they are not included under a specific service account.

Additionally, in order for your push notifications to be secured, I would follow either of these two solutions:

> > To **confirm that the push notification originates from Cloud Pub/Sub**. You could configure **[endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/subscriber#push-subscription)** which only accept messages that contain a secret [token](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/faq#security).
> >
> > **Set up your own push proxy**.  A simple stateless service might pull messages from Pub/Sub and push them from a fixed IP address to your webhook. Pub/Sub offers value in this setup by providing scaling and availability.

Additionally, I'm not sure if you already implemented exactly this and did not work, but **this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45970087/securing-pubsub-push-endpoints-in-node-app-engine?rq=1) from another Stackoverflow issue may be helpful**

Comment: I had thought a similar solution to the second one you proposed. Regarding the first solution the problem I think remain, because I can protect with a service account but the app engine endpoint will still remain with a public access I know will be difficult to sniff the url and the correct request. Thanks

Comment: Did you have a look to [appengine push-handler](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push#authenticating_standard_and_urls)?

Comment: Also documented in the official [gitHub GAE sample section](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/standard_python37/pubsub)